# vue nuxt load css file in a method function with props variable

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to load a .css file after a component event has been fired. Is this possible in vue/nuxt?

scenario
1. component is loaded and props passed in 
2. init event calls method
3. method loads css with a props value

```
export default {
  methods: {
     myLoadCss(){
        (load css from static folder) 
           '/mycss/+this.$props.myCssFolder+/custom.css'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: the `this.$props.myCssFolder` is only loaded after the component is called, so the variable is not available at this time, therefore we have to wait until the var is available before calling the css.